# $_FILES empty when trying to do a file upload

Tags: php

This is driving me crazy.  I'm trying to figure out how to upload a file.  I've got two very simple files, yet it doesn't seem to work.  This first is the file that allows the user to choose the file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
This form allows you to upload a file to the server.<br>

<form action="getfile.php" method="post"><br>
Type (or select) Filename: <input type="file" name="uploadFile">
<input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
</body>
</html>
</code>
```

The second is the php file that handles it:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Process Uploaded File</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

print_r($_FILES);
print "<P>\n";

move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadFile'] ['tmp_name'],
       "../blimages/site/7337/{$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name']}")

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Since -- except for the `print_r` -- I pulled these off a website tutorial on how to do a file upload, I'd think these files are okay.

The `print_r($FILES)` return a completely empty array.

I also checked the `php.ini`.  File uploads are allowed, and the max size is 2M, which I assume is 2 megabytes, which is far larger than the file I've been trying to upload.

What else could be wrong?

Thanks,

Sean.

Comment: Don't forget to indicate which one worked for you by clicking the tick mark beside the answer :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add the proper enctype attribute to your `form` tag:

```
<form action="getfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It's documented here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Also, make sure there's no space between your brackets when you access multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']
```

Comment: The enctype was exactly the problem.  Thank you.

If the other hadn't been from a tutorial website and be supposed to work..  sigh.

Sean.

Comment: Glad to help. It's a very common error. If you think this is the correct/best answer, please don't forget to mark it correct using the green check mark.

Comment: @Sean - don't worry. This is the classical beginner's mistake when it comes to HTML file uploads. It's one of those things you either know or don't know, intuition is useless here.

Answer (score 1):

You shuold use attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in **form** tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add that in Form tag

enctype="multipart/form-data"